# Finding string/varchars that are not contained in any othe string/varhcar in that column

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I'm trying to find strings that are not just distinct, but where that sequence of characters in string is distinct when compared to other values for that field. Basically I'm only trying to find values that are not contained in any of the other values for that column. I've spent a while trying to figure out how to do this but haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Show us some sample data and also your SQL that you have created so far

Comment: I've just been using a temp table for purposes of figuring this out, don't have a real table as of yet.           
  
`CREATE TABLE #words
    (
    WordID int,
    Word varchar(30)
    ) 
 
    Insert into #words Values (1, 'test')
    Insert into #words Values (1, 'gas')
    Insert into #words Values (1, 'gass')
    Insert into #words Values (1, 'bar')` 
  
So obviously from this test result set I don't want gas to return, because it exists as part of gass. I don't really have any sql because I don't even remotely have it working. I've tried doing things with like and not like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you may try something like:

```
declare @table table (wordid int identity, word varchar(50))

insert into @table values
    ('abc')
    ,('abcd')
    ,('ef')
    ,('abcdef')
    ,('ghi')
    ,('klm')
    ,('zxcvb')

select word
from @table t
where not exists (
    select 1 from @table t2
    where charindex(t.word, t2.word) > 0 and t2.wordid != t.wordid
)
```

Output:

```
word
---------
abcdef
ghi
klm
zxcvb
```

Comment: That works. Thanks!. I tried something with charindex earlier, but apparently I wasn't doing it right.